# How to separate nodejs sessions

Tags: node.js, session, chatbot

I have a very simple nodejs chatbot that learns things about a client that is connected to it. For example, if a client says "My name is Bob" and then asks the chatbot "What is my name?" the chatbot will say "Bob" the problem is that if another client connects to the server and then asks the chatbot the same question, the chatbot will also reply with "Bob". I understand I need to implement some way of dealing with sessions but everything I found online about sessions was explaining things about cookies and how to store user authentication.

All I want to do is let each client have his own instance of the server that knows nothing about the other clients.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an in-memory database such as Redis to store information about connected users by identifying them by their id. 
Let's suppose you are using messenger platform for your bot. Each message you receive from Facebook to your webhook comes along with some information, such as the id of user who sent the message, the id of the page to which the message was sent, etc. You can then use Redis to store any information about any user (userID, userName, etc). Once you receive a message, you just query information about the user using their id as the key.

Answer (score 0):

Session is just the variable on server. you can store in variable, array or database (better option in case server restarts). so it totally depends upon your logic.

Let say for each connected user id you will have its data.

```
var userData = {1: {username: "bob" }, 2: {username: "alice", ... }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use cookies, sessions and a session store.

If you use a proper session library, it will create cookies automatically for the user on the client and a session on the server.
On the browser, only the sessionID is stored in the cookie, on the server, you can attach as many properties as you want to the session. To persist them, you can use Redis.

Use a combination of these three libraries (notice the first and second are actually different):

1. express-sessions
2. express-session
3. redis

Then your initialize it in this way ...

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var crypto = require('crypto');
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'A-SECRET-NOBODY-KNOWS',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    genid: (req) => {
            return crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');;
          },
    store: new (require('express-sessions'))({
        storage: 'redis',
        instance: client, // optional 
        collection: 'sessions' // optional 
    })
}));
```

Finally using the sessions is as simply as

```
//read
let token = req.session.token

//write
req.session.token= 'A very secret token';
```

I wrote a [tutorial](https://github.com/rubenrincon/dbximgdemo) that has more information on how to use sessions, scroll down to part 6.